# create a new model raise error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on a **Rails V2.3.2** project, I wanna create a new model, so I run the following command:

```
rails generate model cars name:string owner:string description:text
```

But I got the following error:

```
/home/myname/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
    from /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support.rb:56
...
```

How to get rid of this error?

**P.S.**

I have the code:

```
require 'thread'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
```

in my RakeFile , config/engironment.rb and script/server.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 2, the generate command is:

```
ruby script/generate model car name:string owner:string description:text
```

`rails generate` is the command used in Rails 3

Also, models are singular by convention (use `car` instead of `cars`. It will avoid much head-ache afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert this code before `boot.rb` inside Rakefile, config/environment.rb, script/server:

```
require 'thread'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
```

If you still get the error above you can also add require 'thread' in your boot.rb after the RAILS_ROOT constant was defined:

```
RAILS_ROOT = "#{File.dirname(FILE)}/.." unless defined?(RAILS_ROOT)
require 'thread'
```

Also watch this post: [Gem 1.5 with Rails 2.3.x](http://blog.rubyrockers.com/2011/03/gem-1-5-rails-2-3/)

Comment: I have the above code in the places you mentioned. I checked.

Comment: I have "require 'thread'
require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))" in my RakeFile

Comment: BTW, if you have a project generated with Rails 2.3.x you should not run Rails 3.x commands like: `rails generate`. Use script/generate instead.

Comment: Thank you bor1s, it is just because of my wrong command syntax which has been pointed out by @rubyprince . Thank you anyhow!